# Model - ViewModel sync and filtered ObservableCollections

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm, filtering, observablecollection

I am working with EF and MVVM.
My Model contains this:

```
Public Property Visits As DbSet(Of Visit)
```

The Visit class implements INotifyPropertyChanged and its properties properly raise PropertyChanged events.

My ViewModel contains these properties, used for my views binding (context is my model):

```
Private _BareVisits As ObservableCollection(Of Visit)
    Public Property BareVisits As ObservableCollection(Of Visit)
        Get
            If _BareVisits Is Nothing Then
                _BareVisits = New ObservableCollection(Of Visit)(context.Visits)
                AddHandler _BareVisits.CollectionChanged, AddressOf BareVisits_CollectionChanged
            End If
            Return _BareVisits
        End Get
        Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of Visit))
            _BareVisits = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _Visits As ObservableCollection(Of Visit)
    Public Property Visits As ObservableCollection(Of Visit)
        Get
            If _Visits Is Nothing Then
                _Visits = New ObservableCollection(Of Visit)(
                    BareVisits.Where(
                        Function(V) Not V.IsMediGenerated AndAlso V.IsHistoryParseComplete
                    )
                )
            End If
            Return _Visits
        End Get
        Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of Visit))
            _Visits = value
        End Set
    End Property

Private Sub BareVisits_CollectionChanged(sender As Object, e As NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs)
    Select Case e.Action
        Case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add
            context.Visits.AddRange(e.NewItems.OfType(Of Visit))
            context.SaveChanges()
        Case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove
            context.Visits.RemoveRange(e.OldItems.OfType(Of Visit))
            context.SaveChanges()
        Case Else
            Exit Sub
    End Select
End Sub
```

As you see, the **BareVisits** property is just the DB collection of my Visits.

The **Visits** property (the one my view is bound to) depends on **BareVisits** to return filtered records.

Questions:

1) Which is the best method to save a new visit? By using the event handler posted? Or should I talk to the Model directly and somehow bubble this changes to the ViewModel? If I hook the CollectionChanged handler to the Visits property, do I need this BareVisits property at all?

2) Suppose the changes take place in the Model itself, I suppose I should also perform the record adds / delete to the BareVisits property also. What happens to the Visits property? (the filtered one) I have tried everything and its CollectionChanged event is never fired. Should I tamper with it also by hand?

I just want my view to depict the data changes and I am at a loss.

EDIT: I have also tried to use ICollectionView to filter the raw data (instead of a new ObservableCollection property) but it is not a choice since the data in my datagrid is rendered un-editable this way.

Thank you in advance. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Remove `Private _Visits` and recalc whenever it is asked for. And do a NotifPropChanged when a Visit is added/removed, or as a last resort in that event handler.

Comment: And both setters should be "never used", remove them for clarity.

Comment: If I remove _Visits (this making the property read-only), the getter will be tranformed to this:

`
Return New ObservableCollection(Of Visit)(
    BareVisits.Where(
     Function(V) Not V.IsMediGenerated AndAlso V.IsHistoryParseComplete
    )
   )
`

Won't this result in the ObservableCollection be reconstructed again and again? Could you please explain?

Comment: Yes, it will be reconstructed after each Notify. With the new data.

Comment: Isn't this too heavy performance - wise? I think the whole point of the ObservableCollection is for it to be aware of collection changes and have its view automatically update the changed data than the whole data collection tree.

Comment: Using an oberservable collection where you never plan to bind to it is waisting resources.

Comment: Good point. Any suggestions concerning my scenario? Maybe something I am missing?

Comment: @Core-One: "wasting resources?" Like, what, a millisecond or two of extra processing?  A couple bytes more on the stack?  Unnecessary, maybe. Wasteful? Hardly. Don't tell the new guy to prematurely optimize, it's bad form.